# How to change svg image size without cutting it off?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, svg

Here is my svg image code written with react-native-svg:

```
import React from "react"
import 
  { 
    widthPercentageToDP as wp ,
    heightPercentageToDP as hp
  } from "react-native-responsive-screen";
import Svg, { Rect, Path } from "react-native-svg"

export const motivImageWidth = wp('100%');
export const motivImageHeight = hp('14%');

const MotivationsView = () => {
  return (
    <Svg 
      width={motivImageWidth} 
      height={motivImageHeight} 
      viewBox={"0 0 " + motivImageWidth + " " + motivImageHeight} 
      fill="none"
    >
      <Path
        d="M195 114l5.175 5.175L205.35 114"
        stroke="#fff"
        strokeWidth={3}
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
      />
      <Path
        fillRule="evenodd"
        clipRule="evenodd"
        d="M400 0H0v90c0 8.284 6.716 15 15 15h370c8.284 0 15-6.716 15-15V0z"
        fill="#FDF5F1"
      />
    </Svg>
  )
}

export default MotivationsView
```

Right now I'm creating adaptive design for my app, so I need to change the size of my image based on the screen size, so on other devices my svg image is being cutted off. How can I fix that?

Comment: please try removing this 2 lines of code: ` width={motivImageWidth} 
      height={motivImageHeight}`

Comment: I made that and image just disappeared

Comment: I suspect your viewBox should be constant i.e. just 4 numbers and not dependant on the image height/width.